# (css) :focus background-color como puedo lograr este efecto?

Tags: html, css, focus

:focus + background-color:orange; al darle click al elemento se coloca, en este caso el background-color orange pero mientras esta funcionando al darle click a cualquier otro lugar en toda la pantalla (literal) se quita, quisiera que se mantuviera hasta tocar otro elemento... lo he visto en otra paginas webs y queda genial como puedo lograrlo? se necesita javascript o otra tecnología? gracias

---

```css
 li{
     display: inline-block;
 }

 a{
     padding: 10px;
     color: black;
 }

 a:focus{
     background-color: orange;
 }
```

que el efecto se mantenga aunque clickees en otro lugar ya que por defecto desaparece, aqui dejo un ejemplo con una imagen, aunque interactues en esa pagina se mantendra hasta que clickees en otro elemento con :focus y se pasara en este caso el background y no se quitara hasta darle a otro elemento o pagina espero me hayan entendido xD [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para que tu respuesta sea bienvenida, pon al menos algún ejemplo de ¿qué has intentado? Te dejo un ejemplo para orientarte: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_form_focus2 y con cualquier error, vuelves con algún código o le das a editar a tu pregunta y añades el código.

Comment: si, al darle a la barra del formulario se pone en este caso un border pero al darle click a otro lugar se quita y me gustaria que se mantenga hasta darle click especificamente a otro elemento con el :focus, deje un ejemplo en una nueva respuesta aqui ... gracias por responder no estoy seguro que se pueda solo con css y html...

Comment: Según entiendo, lo que necesitas es la clase `active`. Cuando se da click a un elemento (a, botón), con javascript se le agrega la clase `actice`. Ya con esta clase en CSS o en javascript se le da al elemento el estilo que queramos: color de fondo, subrayados, cambio de texto, etc. PERO ES CON JAVASCRIPT.

Comment: estuve intentando con el a:active pero quedaba permanente.... mañana comienzo con javascript o dentro de unas horas desde cero y tendre en cuenta esta clase gracias a todos por la ayuda y el tiempo! :)

Comment: Mira este ejemplo en JavaScript, es simple y así te orientas: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onfocus

Comment: sii ese es el efecto que quiero lograr :v !

Comment: al darle click a cualquier lado se mantiene pero al darle click a otro elemento se quita y se pasa?

Comment: bueno ya se que se puede hacer con ayuda de javascript, por los ejemplos que me dieron :)

Answer (score 0):

no entendí muy bien tu pregunta pero intenta colocando así como ejemplo:

```
a:focus {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Esto hace que se le coloque el `focus` a todos los `<a href="">` de tu página.

Comment: si lo intente antes pero no me dejaba, ahora ya pude y deje una nueva respuesta aqui pero no se si me explique bien xd